# Problems with Zsh on macOS after update

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, iterm2, macos-catalina

After upgrading to macOS 10.15 I have some serious problems with the console. I got strong problems with rbenv and ruby.

Any new window or tab from the console gives me the following information:

```
user@macbook-name ~ % rbenv -v
rbenv 1.0.0-33-gc7dcaf1
user@macbook-name ~ % which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

I tried reinstalling rbenv. I reinstalled ruby through rbenv. I wrote this line in `~/.zshrc` file:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

But as soon as I close the tab or exit the console window or the entire console, everything was reset. That is, I open, for example, a new tab and in it again:

```
user@macbook-name ~ % which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Tell me, please, how can I fix this?
It’s impossible to work like that.

Answer (score 0):

The following commands helped me:

```
% echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshenv
% echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshenv
% echo 'source $HOME/.zshenv' >> ~/.zshrc
% exec $SHELL
```