# zsh: no matches found: users:update_ratings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, zsh, macos-catalina

Rails 5.1.7. Some of the problems have been described here: [Problems with Zsh on macOS after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58363698/problems-with-zsh-on-macos-after-update)

After upgrading to macOS 10.15 I have problems with rails rake tasks. For example, I have a task that works fine on the server. But locally, I get the following:

```
% rails users:update_ratings[8375]
zsh: no matches found: users:update_ratings[8375]
```

At the same time, for example, this command works:

```
rails c
```

That is, rails for this ruby version are installed.

This is the first time I've come across this. I don’t even understand where to start.

---

**UPD**

The problem is in square brackets.

It works:

```
% rails users:update_ratings
```

This doesn't work:

```
% rails users:update_ratings[8375]
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

For Zsh, this should look like this:

```
% rails users:update_ratings\[8375\]
```

Or:

```
% rails 'users:update_ratings[8375]'
```

---

You can also write this command:

```
unsetopt nomatch
```

More details: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-NOMATCH

> If a pattern for filename generation has no matches, print an error, instead of leaving it unchanged in the argument list. This also applies to file expansion of an initial ‘~’ or ‘=’.